# Rxswift change value of observed object

Tags: swift, observable, rx-swift, subscribe

I am fairly new to Rx and to Reactive Programming in general. I am simply trying to make things work. I'm trying to populate an object after a request to an API (Github's API for the matter):

The object to populate :

```
class GithubUser {
    var login: String?
    var joinDate: Date?
    var email: String?
}
```

The way I try to feed it:

```
class GithubUserRepository {
    static func getUser() -> Observable<GithubUser> {
        let userObservable = BehaviorRelay<GithubUser>(value: GithubUser())
        let login = "Thiryn"
        // GithubService.sharedInstance.getUser does whatever async call to the github API to get a user profile
        GithubService.sharedInstance.getUser(login, success: { (userProfile) in
            userObservable.value.login = login
            userObservable.value.email = userProfile.email
            userObservable.value.joinDate = userProfile.joinedDate
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        return userObservable.asObservable()
    }
}
```

And how I try to consume

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        GithubUserRepository.getUser().subscribe(onNext: { (user) in
            print(user.login ?? "nope")
        }).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
    }
}
```

The result is that I a "nope" the first time, before the request get executed, then I successfully get a result from my request, change the value of the object, but I might do something wrong as the subscribed function is never executed after.
Any thoughts? Thanks!

Edit : I based my try on the [Reactive Values example from RxSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/Documentation/Examples.md#reactive-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use BehaviorRelay like this.
If you expect this method to return only one user, using [Single](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/Documentation/Traits.md#single) would be better.

```
class GithubUserRepository {
    static func getUser() -> Single<GithubUser> {
        return Single.create { single in
            let login = "Thiryn"
            GithubService.sharedInstance.getUser(login, success: { (userProfile) in
                let user = GithubUser()
                user.login = login
                user.email = userProfile.email
                user.joinDate = userProfile.joinedDate
                single(.success(user))
            }) { (error) in
                single(.error(error))
            }
            return Disposables.create {
                // single disposed
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and consume:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        GithubUserRepository.getUser().subscribe(onSuccess: { (user) in
            print(user.login)
        }, onError: { error in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
    }
}
```

Didn't test this code though. It's only to give you idea how should it look.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of clarifications -

First of all, the way to wrap an existing API service into an Observable would be to use `Observable.create {}`. The way you're doing this at the moment is suboptimal (e.g. using a Relay just to store values)

Second, modifying a reference type isn't considered a "change" on the observable stream. The only thing that is considered a change is actually *emitting* a new value onto the stream. (e.g. `relay.accept(newUser)`).

For your situation, the scheme you should follow would be:

```
func myMethod() -> Observable<DataModel> { 
    return Observable.create { observer in 
        myAPIService.doRequest ( result in 
            ... do some stuff ...
            observer.onNext(result)
            observer.onCompleted()

            // or observer.onError(error) if it occured
        }

        return Disposables.create { }
    }
}
```

This is the proper way to wrap your API call inside a Rx-y method, that returns an `Observable` object. You could do the same with `Single.create` if you'd like to return a `Single`.

You should read further on how Rx works, it is not as basic as manipulating the current "value" of things, as things in streams don't really have a "value", it is just values being continuously added into an existing stream.

Answer (score 0):

Your `value` is a reference type. You either need to change it to a `struct` or reinstantiate it every time and assign to the `userObservable` as follows:

```
userObservable.accept(GithubUser(login: login, email: userProfile.email, joinDate: userProfile.joinedDate))
```

Comment: You cannot assign a value like this to a Relay or Observable.